# Google Cloud SQL Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, mobile, backend, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I've started developing for GAE (Google App Engine) and I want to build a REST API using Google Cloud SQL. I currently have a web app in App Engine that works well with Google Cloud SQL but I need to build an API to provide REST services for Android and iOS or any other technology  capable of consume web-services.

I've read many docs in Google about Mobile Backend Starter, Endpoints, etc. I'm not pretty sure how to integrate with my existing Cloud SQL Database. I think I'm almost near to get what I need.

If someone knows a tutorial or documentation to achieve what I need, please share it in here.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org might be one way to go

Comment: Thanks Paul, that should do it but since I'm hosting in GAE, Google Cloud Endpoints seems to be the idieal alternative as decribed in [this](http://darrenoneill.co.uk/post/django-api-gae-cloud-endpoints/) article. Will try to implement that tutorial to see if works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what I needed!

If anyone tries to implement Google Cloud Endpoints using Google Cloud SQL, Python with Django, please follow this [tutorial](http://darrenoneill.co.uk/post/django-api-gae-cloud-endpoints/) You will be able to build a RESTful API with your existing Django Models.

Also, here's a [Youtube Video from GDL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy0tP6_kWJ4) which explains very well how to use ProtoRPC for Python and build your Google Cloud Enpoints APIs. ProtoRPC is a framework for implementing HTTP-based remote procedure call (RPC) service.